Could someone help me understand why the solution to this problem isn't always one?

This is my current logic with respect to this problem, however, after submitting this hard-coded solution, it does not pass all test cases. I would like to know how. Here is my logic:
Ignoring the fact that every solution should be one, my process would be to initially add all of the values together (analogous to having array b filled with ones) then subtract values from the array until the sum is minimized (until any further subtraction of values would cause a negative sum: this is essentially decrementing the multiple of the values of a denoted by the number in the b array). I'm wondering if there is some hidden rule that the elements must be distinct. Nevertheless, could someone help me understand this problem?

Handle an array containing just one number with absolute value greater than one. Try to establish when it will be possible to reach just any target value.

And where does the second array b get input? The problem statement talks about a second array, but there's no place for it to be input and the example is meaningless. Unless we assume that b is just a copy of a?

@JimMischel I know... there is no information given about array b at all. Honestly, I think this is just a poorly designed question.
